# Convert date in format 'Web, 28 Aug 2014 15:47' to proper format

Tags: java, android, date

I have a date which is like so:

Web, 28 Aug 2014 15:47

But I want it to be in the format:

28/08/2014.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `SimpleDateFormatter`. The below example shows how to use one of two instances depending on the length of the input date:

```
String dateString = "Wed, 28 Aug 2014 15:47";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
Date date = null;
if(dateString.length() == "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm".length()) {
    date = dateFormatter.parse(dateString);
} else {
    date = dateFormatter2.parse(dateString);
}
SimpleDateFormat destinationFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(destinationFormatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks! But what if the date is not always 'Wed, 28 Aug 2014 15:47', what if it was 'Thu, 28 Aug 2014 15:47"' how would I parse it then?

Comment: `Date date = dateFormatter.parse("Your date");`

Comment: Also, this gives me the error Unparseble date 'Wed, 28 Aug 2014' at position 16?

Comment: @Callum `Wed, 28 Aug 2014` is different than `Wed, 28 Aug 2014 15:47`. In this case you can create two `SimpleDateFormatter`, one for each format. You can select which one to use depending on the length of the date string.